# Visual Studio Code and Python 3.9 integration

Tags: python

Please be gentle with me as this is my first post and I am new to Python. I have downloaded and installed Python 3.9 on Windows 10 64 bit. This all seems to work fine and I can code, debug and run Python scripts within the IDLE IDE.

The next step was to install Visual Studio Code and the Python extension - which I have done. However, the Microsoft instructions state that I need to click on the status bar and select Python 3.9. I do not have a Python option in my status bar…

[Image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRoTw.png)

No doubt I am being a numpty but can someone please point me in the right direction?

Many thanks

Comment: Create a `.py` file and it'll probably trigger what you want to see

Answer (score 0):

First of all click on 'open folder' and open your programming folder. Now create a new file(ctrl + n) named [file name].py. Now press ctrl + shift + p. Now Click on 'Enter Interpreter path' and now on 'find'. Now you can browse up for your python.exe file and it's done!

Comment: Hope this helped you out!